# Import data from old Jira version with HSQL DB to higher Jira version Oracle 12c

Tags: jira, oracle12c, hsqldb

I am a beginner and in my company currently using Jira version 7.11.0 configured with oracle 12.1.0.1 database, Windows and it have some new  data with it.

My task to import the old data from previously used old Jira version (6.1.1) which has internal HSQLDB and this old Jira setup is on  different Windows server. Can anyone please explain the process in detail, I got error when tried to export the old Jira 6.1.1 data by Import & Export > Backup System which creates a zip with two xml files (entities.xml, activeObjects.xml) but on tried to import by 'project import' on current using Jira 7.11.0, shows error saying it's old version data build number 6155 and currently running version build number 711000.Under 'External system Import' don't find an option for 'Zip'.

Please share any tool or plugin if required and is possible to migrate the data without update the Jira version 7.11 further.

Comment: You will almost certainly have to upgrade the old Jira server to 7.11.0 before you can migrate the data, as the schema has changed in the newer version.

Comment: Thanks for replying.Can pls possible to explain the further steps

Comment: Check documentation for Jira upgrade to 7.11.0 from 6.1.1. That isn't something you're going to get a step-by-step answer to on this forum.